# vue-tsc failing with Error "Referenced Project may not disable emit" on vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ts-node, vue-tsc

When updating my project to use the latest `@vue/tsconfig` version (version `0.5.1` as of this writing) the command `vue-tsc` fails with error

```
Referenced project 'd:/repos/project/tsconfig.node.json' may not disable emit
```

The project is build with Vite and Vue3 and was working without a problem prior to this update. Adding a `"noEmit": false` to the specified tsconfig fixes this.

This error comes from a breaking change of `vue-tsc` setting `"noEmit": true` in their default tsconfig `@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json` which my tsconfig extends.

My question is: are there any drawbacks from adding `"noEmit": false` to the `tsconfig.node.json` (which is used by vite). I have read, that `noEmit` tells typescript to not emit any output (like JavaScript files or type declarations) when it compiles my code.

Below are some minimal tsconfigs both for vue and vite used in my project (located in the project root folder):

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*", "playwright.config.*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "noEmit": false // this was added
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `@vue/tsconfig@0.5.1` instead of `vue-tsc`.

The [upstream `tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/vuejs/tsconfig/blob/v0.5.1/tsconfig.json#L5) addition of `"noEmit": true` is likely breaking your project because you're also running `vue-tsc --noEmit` somewhere in your `package.json` scripts.

If you look at [a recent GitHub commit](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue/commit/9b27fdf31387e64d10a83cdafee760f7d958b6e7) in the `create-vue` starter kit, you'll notice they repeated the same `"noEmit": true` addition in local `tsconfig.json` files, but removed the `--noEmit` flag to match, making a zero-sum change:

```
// package.json
- "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.app.json --composite false"
+ "type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force"

// tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.node.json
+ "noEmit": true,
```

On your end, you should be able to solve your problem by updating your `package.json` scripts to match [theirs](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue/blob/v3.9.1/template/config/typescript/package.json#L2-L6).

---

> My question is: are there any drawbacks from adding "noEmit": false to
> the tsconfig.node.json (which is used by vite).

I'm far from a TypeScript expert, but my understanding is you don't ever want to emit files from TS when using Vite, since Vite is handling the compilation for you. (I would imagine `vite build` passes the necessary flags behind the scenes.)

That said, if you keep this flag disabled and don't see any superfluous files being generated throughout your project, then it's probably fine? (Regardless — I would still follow `create-vue`'s approach.)

Also [see this SO answer on usage of this flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002137/typescript-noemit-use-case).

---

As an aside, it's worth mentioning that `create-vue` now generates a `tsconfig.json` that looks like:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

You may have an easier time following along with future changes by updating your codebase to match this structure. You can browse those files here: https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue/tree/v3.9.1/template/tsconfig/base.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and links.

Two things I want to add: When running `vue-tsc` without the option --noEmit, the command will still crash with the same error unless the `noEmit: false` is added. Second: Using the create-vue script, the newly created project contains now 3 tsconfig files. However, running the provided `npm run build` or `npm run type-check` command will generate additional tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo files. Those are apparently the only two files generated by vue-tsc (I suppose I should add them to gitignore)

Comment: I have also edited my question to the correct package name as you suggested

Comment: @Scorix That is the behavior I'm seeing with `vue-tsc` as well.

In terms of the `.tsbuildinfo` files, those aren't technically "emitted" files. Emits would be `.js` or `.d.ts` files. [`.tsbuildinfo` intentionally doesn't respect the `--noEmit` flag.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30661)

I'm not sure why previous versions of `vue-tsc` didn't output `.tsbuildinfo` files, as [they should be present for all composite projects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html). I'm seeing the same on my end. You are safe to Git-ignore.